# struggling with add to cart local storage logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
   $scope.toCart = function(id,item){

      var toSaveArray = [];
      var toSaveObj = {
        id: item._id,
        name : item.name,
        image : item.image[0],
        price : item.price,
        discount_price : item.discount_price,
        qty : 1
      }

      toSaveArray.push(toSaveObj);

      var fromSaved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

      if(fromSaved){
          for(i=0;i<fromSaved.length;i++){
          if(fromSaved[i].id == id){
            fromSaved[i].qty += 1;
            toSaveArray.push(fromSaved);
          }
        }
      }

      localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(toSaveArray));

   }
```

If item exist, add one qty, else just add the object into the array. But with that simple logic, I failed to have a working code. Above code is broken.

Comment: `above code is broken` How so? What is it doing?

Comment: What specifically is broken?

Comment: I think your logic here is back to front `toSaveArray.push(fromSaved);` From what I can see, it would make a lot more sense to push the `toSaveObj` to the existing save ( `fromSaved` ) then resave that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve some logic mistakes:

```
$scope.toCart = function(id, item) {
    var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    if (!cart) {
        cart = [];
    }

    var index = cart.findIndex(function (cartItem) {
        return cartItem.id === item._id;
    });

    if (index !== -1) {
        cart[index].qty += 1;
    } else {
        cart.push({
            id: item._id,
            name : item.name,
            image : item.image[0],
            price : item.price,
            discount_price : item.discount_price,
            qty : 1
        });
    }

    localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));

}
```

Comment: will there be error if the cart is empty for the very first time?

Comment: this is actually a really smart solution!

Comment: actually I can avoid loop because findIndex will find a unique id, correct? u have a typo, qty not qti.

Comment: You can use `.filter` for it. Array API is excludes loops at all

Comment: Couse I do not understand why you need it. This solution guarantees what only one item with unique ID is present in the cart. It checks item presence, and if it true, increases `qty`, else push new item to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was doing wrong at those steps:

- Comparing previous `item._id` with parameter `id`
- Always saving the `item` parameter
- Doing an unecessary **for**

  ```
  $scope.toCart = function(item){

      var toSaveArray = [];
      var toSaveObj = {
          id: item._id,
          name : item.name,
          image : item.image[0],
          price : item.price,
          discount_price : item.discount_price,
          qty : 1
      };

      var fromSaved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

      if(fromSaved){
          var savedItem = $filter('filter')(fromSaved, {id: item._id});
          if (savedItem) {
              fromSaved[fromSaved.indexOf(savedItem[0])].qty++;
          }

          toSaveArray = fromSaved;
      } else {
          toSaveArray.push(toSaveObj);
      }

      localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(toSaveArray));
  };
  ```

The above code should cover for all that.